# scikit-learn cross_validate() returns negative values with 'neg_mean_squared_error'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, cross-validation

Update:
Thank you, Ben Reiniger. the "neg" means negative. so the value is negative.

--

I created a "cross_validation" to calculate performance(MSE) for each model. Below is my code

```
def cross_validation(models, X, y, cv = 5):
    if len(models['model']) != len(models['model_name']):
        return 'length error'
    
    res = []
    for ind in range(len(models['model_name'])):
        print('Model:',models['model_name'][ind] )
        cv_results = cross_validate(models['model'][ind], X, y, cv=cv, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error')
        res.append(cv_results['test_score'].mean())
    cv_res = pd.DataFrame({'Model': models['model_name'], 'CV_result': res})
    return cv_res


lasso = Lasso(**best_params['Best_params'][0])
svm = LinearSVR(**best_params['Best_params'][1])
rfm = RandomForestRegressor(**best_params['Best_params'][2])
xgb = XGBRegressor(learning_rate=0.03, **best_params['Best_params'][3])

models = ['lasso', 'SVM', 'RandomForest', 'XGB']
best_models = {'model_name':models, 'model':[lasso,svm,rfm,xgb]}


cross_validation(best_models, X, Y, cv = 5)



    Model           CV_result
0   lasso           -0.911512
1   SVM             -1.707363
2   RandomForest    -0.727669
3   XGB             -0.769415
```

MSE should be non-negative, right? So anyone knows why I got negative results?

Comment: The "neg" in `neg_mean_squared_error` is short for "negative", and literally means the output is the negative of the mse. (That's done because optimizers in sklearn always maximize the scores they produce.)

Comment: Thank you. In the scikit learn "3.3. Metrics and scoring: quantifying the quality of predictions", it says ‘neg_mean_absolute_error’ linked to function "metrics.mean_squared_error", so I thought it should be positive.